# What is the best way to reserve a very large virtual address space (TBs) in the kernel?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, tlb, page-fault

I'm trying to manually update TLB to translate new virtual memory pages into a certain set of physical pages in the kernel space. I want to do this in `do_page_fault` so that whenever a load/store instruction happens in a particular virtual address range (not already assigned), it put a page table entry in TLB in advance. The translation is simple. For example, I would like the following piece of code work properly:

```
int d;
int *pd = (int*)(&d + 0xffff000000000000);
*pd = 25;                  // A page fault occurs and TLB is updated
printk("d = %d\n", *pd);   // No page fault (TLB is already up-to-date)
```

So, the translation is just a subtraction by `0xffff000000000000`. I was wondering what is the best way to implement the TLB update functionality?

**Edit**: The main reason for doing that is to be able to reserve a large virtual memory space in the kernel. I just want to handle page faults in a particular address range in the kernel. So, first I have to reserve the address range (maybe exceeds the 100TB limitation). Then, I have to implement a page cache for that particular range. If it is not possible, what is the best solution for that?

Comment: The TLBs are a hardware cache for the contents of the page tables, and cannot be accessed by software.

Comment: What is the best way to reserve a very large virtual address space (TBs) in the kernel? I supposed I could do it by updating TLB and a page cache.

Comment: To edit your question, click "edit". Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).